# transparent home directory encryption

Tags: server, encryption, home-directory, ecryptfs

**#1** I'm very new to the ubuntu home directory encryption or rather ecryptfs
folder encryption. I read about the same within Dustin's blog & tried
implementing it.
Problem or query is
my home directory is encrypted & has a www folder ... now when I reboot the
system the decryption doesnt happen at startup/boot & apache is not able to
find the files rather the folder www since it is not mounted ... in order to
mount it I have to login ....
is there a way by which an encrypted home / private folder can be mounted at
boot without human intervention ?

**#2** I have installed ubuntu server 11.10 & had selected "encrypt home directory" when installing the same. With ubuntu things are working transparently even after reboot & without logging in. Kindly can anyone pls explain or guide on the same ?

Answer (score 2):

**#1** There is no way of unlocking the encrypted home folder without entering the password. You should move your www folder out of your home folder an reconfigure apache. The default for that would be `/var/www`.

**#2** If you selected "encrypt home folder" during install it only encrypted the home folder of the user you created during install. If the files of e.g. apache are saved somewhere else (even in `/home/some_folder`) it would work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I had problems logging in and ended up changing my login password from a different user account. When I changed it back it automatically started decrypted at start up again. If your log in password is the same as your encryption password then it will automatically decrypt when you login. So either change your loging password or your encrypted folder password so that they are the same.